# Changing the controller section in the URL path, without changing the model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following model:

```
class Style < ActiveRecord::Base
```

I have come a long way with this model, and have many link_to routes and other references to `Style` ... it would pain me to change them all.

Is it possible to circumvent the typical Rails way and have all style objects appear as

```
www.example.com/devices/device-name
```

instead of

```
www.example.com/styles/device-name
```

without actually changing the model name `Style` -> `Device`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

- Use `devices` as resources
- Override the controller name
- Use a named helper to keep the existing path helpers

In routes.rb,

```
resources :devices, controller: 'styles', as: 'styles'
```

Comment: That's fantastic. Do you know how to perform redirects from the old Style routes with the appropriate status?

Comment: Wait, if I follow your suggestion wouldn't I have to change all my links to devices_path, etc?

Comment: you can use `as` to override named helpers. so you dont have to modify your link_to code